# Trying (and failing) to change the color under a UITableView

Tags: uitableview, view, uinavigationcontroller, background-color

I have a UITableView, displayed within a UINavigationController.  I'm trying to change the color of the view under the table, so that when you pull down on the table you see something other than white.

I've tried both of these:

```
self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Separately and together.  Still seeing the white.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
 self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] init];
 self.tableView.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: That worked - doesn't look exactly how I wanted, but that's my problem.  I didn't realize that the white was actually affecting the colors in front. I'll figure that out.  Thanks for your help!